# Helidon MP MicroProfile Application Not Emitting Tracing info: Windows 11 + Jaeger 1.46.0

Tags: windows, jaeger, helidon

I am trying to setup tracing in a quickstart Helidon MP project following the student guide instructions.

I have a windows 11 machine.

I have completed the steps but jaeger search is
neither showing Service helidon-greet
nor any tracing information.

Please help!

Steps done
0. Created the project using Helidon version `3.2.1` CLI for windows https://helidon.io/docs/v3/#/about/cli

1. Install and run `jaeger-1.46.0-windows-amd64`
2. Add in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.helidon.tracing</groupId>
       <artifactId>helidon-tracing-jaeger</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

3. Added following lines in microprofile-config.properties

```
    tracing.service=helidon-greet
    tracing.sampler-type=const
    tracing.sampler-param=1
```

4. Build

```
mvn clean package
java -jar target/helidon-mp.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

*This was resolved by the poster himself, hence adding his solution here:*

I am using Helidon version 3.2.1 and therefore there may be difference in the tracing OOTB integration with Jaeger which now has moved to OpenTelemetry as per MicroProfile 6.0 specifications.
I have resolved the issue by adding more properties int the config
as per
https://helidon.io/docs/v3/#/mp/tracing#jaeger-tracing:

```
tracing.service=helidon-greet
tracing.sampler-type=const
tracing.sampler-param=1

# added more config fields
tracing.enabled=true
tracing.protocol=http
tracing.host=localhost
tracing.port=14250
```